# LLVM getelementptr: Integer type of first index

Tags: c++, pointers, llvm, llvm-ir

Every time an address is being calculated for a variable, LLVM uses a `GetElementPtrInst` or `GEPOperator` object to specify the indices which "walk" the pointer operand structure. Since a `getelementptr` pointer operand is always (as the name already says) a pointer, the first index in the `getelementptr` operator is used to "[step through](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#why-is-the-extra-0-index-required)" that pointer.

My question is, since the first index is used to step through the pointer, it should always be an integer object with a bit width of whatever the pointer size in bits is (retrieved via [DataLayout::getPointerSizeInBits()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a21ae5af9c62928bb06c66379017bdda1)). Does that simply mean, for programs compiled on x86-64, said bit width is always 64 bit?

If so, why do I get an `i32 0` `ConstantInt` index as the first index, even though the bit width is 64 bits and the pointer operand of a `getelementptr` is always a pointer?

```
%struct.nested_container = type { i32, %struct.nested_container*, %struct.nested_container* }

; ...

%46 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.nested_container, %struct.nested_container* %45, i32 0, i32 2
```

This is the IR generated by clang, no intervention on my behalf was made here. The first index is of `i32 0`, even though bit width is 64 bits. The second index is `i32 2` since the `getelementptr` now "walks" inside a struct, where indices are always of `i32` type. It's the first index that irks me.

Hope to get an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: The GEP indices aren't related to size, they're indices. That they're 32-bit means that structs can have at most 2³² fields. And: If you want a pointer to the first byte *after* the object you're pointing to, index 1 will give you that... do you see?

Comment: @arnt I know that. But that is not what my question is about. The program is compiled for the x86-64 architecture. in **all** programs, and even the Linux kernel for which I created an LLVM IR for, the first index was always of a `i64` type (Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383342/the-gep-instruction-i32-vs-i64)). Just in this case, its an `i32` index.

Comment: The type doesn't really matter... it matters in one case, namely when it's not constant. Supplying an i64 in that case gives support for arrays larger than 2³² entries, which I imagine some users want. In all other cases the index is constant (all but the last indices must be constant) and the code that I've looked at so far just just asserts that it's a constant integer, without caring about the niceties.

Comment: @arnt I have to correct you here, the indices can be both constant and non-constant, except for struct indices which have to be constant at all times. For pointers or arrays the indices can even be an integer variable, same as it is used in C: `array[i]` or in pointers: `ptr + i`. But it makes sense what you said about the index being `i32` or `i64`. Even if what I said about the pointer size being 64 bits, for a program compiled for a 32-bit architecture the index would then be always of `i32` type. Just thought there was going to be a more consistent algorithm behind creating the indices.

Comment: Huh. Makes sense. Now I wonder if this has changed since I learned it, or whether it's been like that always.